# Python function + dict

Tags: python, function, dictionary, switch-statement

Sorry it may be very basic stuff. I'm new to python and cant put my finger on what's wrong here

I have this dictionary:

```py
Board = {'top-L': ' ', 'top-M': ' ', 'top-R': ' ',
         'mid-L': ' ', 'mid-M': ' ', 'mid-R': ' ',
         'low-L': ' ', 'low-M': ' ', 'low-R': ' '}
```

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a number 1-9, convert it to dict keys representing these places and return True if value == ' ':

```py
def CheckSpace(Space):  # Will return True if space is available
    switcher = {
        1: 'top-L',
        2: 'top-M',
        3: 'top-R',
        4: 'mid-L',
        5: 'mid-M',
        6: 'mid-R',
        7: 'low-L',
        8: 'low-M',
        9: 'low-R',
    }
    return Board.get(switcher) == ''
```

Error : TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
Can someone give me a tip please?

***edit
I guess i can write that function like this:

```
def CheckSpace(Space):#Will return True if space is available
    if space == 1:
        place = Board.get('top-L')
    if space == 2:
        place = Board.get('top-M')
    if space == 3:
        place = Board.get('top-R')
    if space == 4:
        place = Board.get('mid-L')
#.... and so on to 9..
return place
```

But I'm trying to use something equivalent to switch case

Comment: Only [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3.1/glossary.html#term-hashable) types can be used as keys in a Dictionary. `dict` is not hashable. See: [DictionaryKeys](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Board.get(switcher) == ''`

switcher is a dict. Maybe you want `Board.get(switcher.get(Space)) == ' '`

Answer (score 1):

The `.get` method accepts a key. You passed in `switcher` which is a dictionary (`dict`s are not hashable, hence the error).

Get the key first using `.get`;

E.g. `switcher.get(Space)`

And then: `Board.get(switcher.get(Space)) == ' '`